# Hide a Brainf*** greeting in other code

Tags: popularity-contest, polyglot, brainfuck

The goal is to write a program (anything except explicit brainfuck) which prints [Barney Stinson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barney_Stinson)'s best rule:

> New is always better.

when interpreted normally, but

> Legen... wait for it... dary!

When processed with a Brainfuck interpreter.

May the most popular bro win. You have 72 hours to be legendary.

Comment: Not sure `code-golf` is the best tag for this challenge. IMHO `popularity-contest` would be better.

Comment: @Florent, feel free to edit, I'm new here

Comment: Whose Barney? The purple dinosaur? Fred's BFF?

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian How I met Your Mother character, see edit

Comment: Samoth, I agree with @florent, but neither he nor I can edit as you need 1000 reputation to edit someone else's question. You can do it yourself though if you think it's a good idea.

Comment: @steveverrill strange, on StackOverflow you can edit with 1 rep, but it have to be approved

Comment: Yeah, you can "suggest" with 1 rep, but the approval process the edit could take hours. It's better to do it yourself, as you have done.

Comment: Can someone please create the tag "bro-contest"?

Comment: @Florent if the challenge is intended to be won by the shortest answer, I don't think you should retag it to a popularity contest. Samoth, in case you don't know, in a popularity contest the winner is chosen by voters - the answer with the highest vote wins. If you want your contest to be won by the answer with shortest code, please retag your question as a code-golf, and if you want it to be a popularity contest, please edit your question.

Comment: I think reusing somebody else's Brainfuck code is poor sport for these competitions.

Comment: @grovesNL as it would be the exact same code, no. I could even have include it in the question

Comment: @Samoth: That assumes that everyone independently found the shortest way to write that string in Brainfuck, when there is no obvious shortest path to write strings. It's completely different than writing something like `echo "text"`. An extra plus sign before a loop will change the entire procedure, because of how the characters have to be created. Likewise using two loops instead of one loop could either increase or decrease the length of your code, and due to the ASCII characters, it's not obvious which will occur until you've already written it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### C#

So I decided to get a little more... creative with my entry. The Brainfuck code is embedded into the C# as the various operators (not in comments or in hardcoded strings), while the C# code itself operates on a similar principal to the way Brainfuck prints characters (meaning there are no hardcoded strings, and C# generates each individual character as an integer then casts it to a char when printing).

I'm sure I could have made this more elegant, but it took me long enough to finish as it is.

Everything was tested on [this JavaScript Brainfuck interpreter](http://www.iamcal.com/misc/bf_debug/) by [Cal Henderson](http://www.iamcal.com/) and with Visual Studo 2012's C# compiler (targeted at .NET framework v4.0).

```cs
using System;

namespace Polyglot
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var a = new short[50];

            short _1 = 72;
            short _2 = 0;
            short _3 = 0;
            short _4 = 0;
            short _5 = 0;
            short _6 = 0;
            short _7 = 97;
            short _8 = 0;
            short _9 = 0;
            short _10 = 0;
            short _11 = 0;
            short _12 = 0;
            short _13 = 0;
            short _14 = 0;
            short _15 = 0;
            short _16 = 46;
            short _19 = 0;
            short _20 = 0;
            short _21 = 0;

            if( 0 >= 0 )
            {
                ++_1;
                ++_1;
                ++_1;
                ++_1;
            }

            a[ -1 < 0 ? 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 : 0 + 1 > 1 ? 0 : 0 ] = 9001;

            if( 7 < 42 )
            {
                ++_1;
                ++_1;
            }

            Console.Write( (char)_1 );

            _2 = 101;
            _1 += 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1;

            _3 = 42 > 7 ? 110 + 9 : 1 + 1;

            a[ -1 < 0 ? 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 : 0 > 0 ? 0 : 0 ] = 9001;

            if( 1 < 2 )
                _4 = 32;

            Console.Write( (char)_2 );

            ++_1;
            _5 = 105;

            Console.Write( (char)_3 );

            --_1;

            _6 = 115;

            Console.Write( (char)_4 );

            ++_1;
            ++_1;
            ++_1;
            _1 += 1 + 1 + 5;

            Console.Write( (char)_5 );

            --_1;
            --_1;

            if( 42 > 41 )
            {
                ++_1;
                ++_1;
                ++_1;
            }

            a[ -1 < 0 ? 0 : 10 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 > 5 ? 0 : 0 ] = 9001;

            if( 42 < 9001 )
                Console.Write( (char)_6 );

            Console.Write( (char)_4 );
            Console.Write( (char)_7 );

            if( 12 > 11 && 11 > 10 )
            {
                _8 = 108;
                _9 = _3;
            }
            else
            {
                ++_1;
                ++_1;
                ++_1;
            }

            a[ -1 < 0 ? 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 : 1 > 2 ? 0 : 0 ] = 9001;

            if( _4 < _1 )
            {
                ++_1;
                Console.Write( (char)_8 );
            }
            else if( _4 > _19 && _2 > _20 )
            {
                ++_21;
                ++_21;
                ++_21;
                ++_21;
                ++_21;
                _21 += (short)( _21 + 36 );
            }

            a[ -7 < 9 ? 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 : 4 > 8 ? 9 : 9 ] = (short)( 12 < 10 ? -_4 : _9 );
            Console.Write( (char)_9 );

            if( _4 > _9 )
            {
                ++_1;
                ++_1;
                ++_1;
            }

            a[ -9 < 7 ? 10 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 : 6 > 7 ? 0 : 0 ] = _21;

            if( 1 < 0 )
                return;
            else
            {
                ++_1;
                Console.Write( (char)_7 );
            }

            _10 += 5 + 4 + 1 + 2 + 8 + 9 + 1 + 91;
            Console.Write( (char)_10 );

            if( 10 > _4 ) ++_21; else a[ -0 < 0 ? 5 + 6 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 9 : 1 > 2 ? 0 : 9 ] = 50;

            if( _21 <= _4 )
                _11 = 58 + 57;

            Console.Write( (char)_11 );

            if( _2 <= _8 )
                Console.Write( (char)_4 );
            else if( 1 >= 2 )
                return;
            else if( 42 >= _4 )
                _1 += ++_21;
            else
            {
                a[ -99 < --_1 ? --_1 - _1 : 44 > 12 ? 9 : 7 ] = (short)( _2 < _4 ? _21 : 6 );
                throw new Exception();
            }

            switch( _4 )
            {
                case 32:
                    var x = (char)( (short)( _4 + 66 ) );
                    Console.Write( x );
                    break;
                default: break;
            }

            _12 += (short)( ++_12 + ( ++_1 ) + 1 + 1 + 1 );
            Console.Write( (char)_12 );

            _13 += (short)( 39 + 38 + 39 );
            Console.Write( (char)_13 );

            if( _12 < _13 )
                Console.Write( (char)_13 );

            if( _13 >= _4 )
            {
                _14 = (short)( 500 - ( - ( 50 ) ) - ( --_1 ) - 90 - ( -4 ) - 267 );
                Console.Write( (char)_14 );
            }

            switch( _1 )
            {
                case 52:
                    _15 += (short)( ++_1 + ( ++_21 ) );
                    break;
                default:
                    _15 += (short)( 15 + ( ++_1 ) + 2 );
                    break;
            }

            Console.Write( (char)_15 );

            if( _16 <= 3521 && _21 < _4 )
                Console.WriteLine( (char)_16 );

            _16 = (short)( Int16.Parse( "54" ) % 2 );
            _20 = (short)( Int16.Parse( "99" ) / ( _1 > _4 ? 3 : 0 ) );
            _1 = (short)( 02.23 );

            if( _16 > 9 || _20 >= 52 )
                _1 += (short)( ( ++_1 ) + _21 );

            a[ -0 < 0 ? -52 - ( --_20 ) : 1 > 0 ? 1 : 2 ] = (short)( _12 < _19 ? Int16.Parse( "19" ) : 44 );
            _12 -= (short)f( --_19 / 19.467d );

            if( _12 > _14 )
                _19 += (short)( _19 + 1 + _3 + 5 );

            a[ -904 < 409 ? 4 + ( ++_4 ) + 4 : 49 > 50 ? 49 : 50 ] = (short)( 50 < 99 ? _4 + 669.2452 : 0 );

            if( 44 > ++_4 )
                a[ -9 < 6 ? 6 + ( ++_4 ) : 9 > 2 ? 44 : 8 ] = 3;
        }

        private static double f( double x )
        {
            return x < 12 ? x + 13.22 : x < 6 ? x + 90.45 : 5555; 
        }
    }
}
```

This is the original Brainfuck code I wrote for this challenge:

```brainfuck
> +++++ +++
[ - < +++++ ++++ > ]
< ++++ .
+++++
> ++
[ - < +++++ +++++ > ]
< . ++ . -- . +++++ ++++ .
----
> +++++ +
[ - < ----- ----- > ]
< ... >>
+++++ +
[ - < +++++ > ]
< ++ . >>
+++++ +++++ ++
[ - < +++++ +++++ > ] <
- . >
+++++ +
[ - < ---- > ] <
++ . +++++ +++ .
> ++
[ - < +++++ > ]
< + . < . >>
+++
[ - < ----- > ] <
+ . +++++ ++++ . +++ .
< . > ----- ---- . +++++ +++++ + .
<< ... > . >>
++++
[ - < ---- > ] < .
--- . >
++++
[ - < ++++ > ]
< + .
> ++
[ - < +++ > ]
< + . < + .
```

When running the C# code through a Brainfuck interpreter, you end up with the following commands (notice the addition of the square brackets at the beginning, these are from the array declaration and don't do anything, since the cell under the memory pointer in the array will already be 0):

```brainfuck
[] > +++++ +++
[ - < +++++ ++++ > ]
< ++++ .
+++++
> ++
[ - < +++++ +++++ > ]
< . ++ . -- . +++++ ++++ .
----
> +++++ +
[ - < ----- ----- > ]
< ... >>
+++++ +
[ - < +++++ > ]
< ++ . >>
+++++ +++++ ++
[ - < +++++ +++++ > ] <
- . >
+++++ +
[ - < ---- > ] <
++ . +++++ +++ .
> ++
[ - < +++++ > ]
< + . < . >>
+++
[ - < ----- > ] <
+ . +++++ ++++ . +++ .
< . > ----- ---- . +++++ +++++ + .
<< ... > . >>
++++
[ - < ---- > ] < .
--- . >
++++
[ - < ++++ > ]
< + .
> ++
[ - < +++ > ]
< + . < + .
```

Answer (score 6):

## Smalltalk

```
"adding adding all the time"
"1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1" "is not fine"
"more to come / going far" 
"+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1"
"all that work for a single char"

"happy me / a loop to start" 
"[>++>+++>++++>+++++<<<<-]"
"was it code or just a fart?"
"adding adding / thats not fine"
"+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1"

">>+" 'New is always better.' "shall I " print
">+.++.--.+++++++++.----------.<<----...<+++++++"
"the garbage here gives us no hint"
".>>+++++++++++.>---.++++++++" 

"hurray a change to stop the pain" 
".>---------.<<<<.>>" 
"the author now has in his brain"
"-----------------.>>-----.+++.<<<<.>>>.>++."
"We all agree the time is here"
"<<<...<.>>--.>--------.>--.+++++++.<<<<."
"to finish this and have a beer"
```

type into a workspace and press "doIt", or send to BF.
BF stolen from the other posters - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript / Brainfuck

Ungolfed version as it is not a code-golf contest :

```javascript
var outputString='';
'+++++++@++++[>++@/+@@>@/+@+@++>++++++@/+>+@++@/+@@+++++@/>@+@+++++@/+++@+<@/<<<<-]>>>@-.>++.+@/+@@.--.>.<-@/.@<@<++...<-.@/>>>>+++++@++++.<-@/-@-.@+@/+@+@+++++@/.>-@--@/.<<<<.>>>@---.>---@/-@@-@/.@+@++.<<<@/<@.@>>>+++@/.@@>@/+@+@.<<<@/...<@.>>>--@/---.---.>--.+++++++.<<<<+.<'
  .split('/')
  .forEach(function(e) {
    var matched=e.match(/[^@]*@/g);
    if (matched) {
      var asciiCode=0;
      for(var i=0;i<matched.length;i++) {
        asciiCode=matched[i-0].length-1+10*asciiCode;
      }
      outputString+=String.fromCharCode(asciiCode);
    }
  });
  alert(outputString);
```

That was the occasion for me to learn BF and that was fun :)
The difficulty was to **never** use `,` as BF interprets it as user input and be sure that byte is 0 before using `[]` for accessing elements of arrays.
The JS encoding is pretty simple, each strings before `/` encode a character and each string length before `@` defines ASCII code in decimal. (`+++++++@++++[>++@` = `78` = `N`)

You can test Brainfuck here : http://copy.sh/brainfuck/

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/Cubically/cubically) ([TIO](https://tio.run/##VU7NCsMgDH6gkAztmkOR4HuMHbaeBr3usKd3SYzSBpTvzy/u3/dnfx3HrzVYId2S3kvlLTtSpTJk5aty00fGHWUjd82E6rh7oSyPynIOyHaPBn0J07oUmrq4arj7ur3Y4NNdcjFjZRagsS1RZUSS06@t1rFusyFBHSIS6EOlAEzs5qSWJRGyvYZw2CE6smN9kdJAZGnW6Bdb@wM)) / BF ([TIO](https://tio.run/##VU5LCgIxDD1QSKQdJ4uhhN5DXKggiOBC8Pw1SdMyE2h5v770/r29Ps/f490arJBOSe@l8pYdqVIZsvJVuekj446ykTtmQnXcvVCWS2XZB2Q7R4O@hGkdCk1dXDXcfd1ebPDqLrmYsTIL0NiWqDIiye7XVutYt9mQoA4RCfShUgAmdnNSy5II2V5DOOwQHdmxvkhpILI0a/SLrf0B))

```
+5+1/1+5+3@6:2/1+5+5+1@6+2@6:5/1+3@6:5+1/1+5+5+1@6:5+2/1+5+5+2@6:5/1+3@6:5+2/1+5+5@6:5+5+2@6:2/1+5+53[@6>:5+2/1+5+5@6>:4/1+5+5+3@6+>:5+2/1+55+2@6:5/1+3@6>:5+3/1+55@6>:2/1+551@6<<<<<-]>:5+3./1+552-@66>+.:2/1+5+51.@6--.>:5+1/1+5+5+2@6:1/1+5@6+++++.>----...>+++++++.<<+++++++++.<----.++++++++.>---.>>.<<<---.>-----.+++.>>.<<<+++.>++.>...>.<<<-----.---.>--.+++++++.>>+.
```

*(Updated 8/4/17 to account for language changes in Cubically)*

Basically this just uses as many characters from the BF program as it can in the Cubically program, then sticks the rest of the BF program on the end of it. No forced termination with `&`/`E` in the Cubically program is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

### Python / BrainF**k, 362 chars

BrainF**k code taken from Clément Renaud's deleted answer.

**Edit** - Initial null character no longer printed.

```python
t='++++++++++_+++++++|^+++++++|+[>++>+++%>++++>+++++<<<<-||]+++++++++++|*+++++++++++++@+>>+.>+||.++.|--.+++++++++.--|^--------.<<----..._<+++++|++.>|>+++++&++++++.>---.+=+++++++|.>---------.<<^<<.>>--||-----|--~-----|---.>>-----~.+++.<<<<.>|>>.*>++.<<<...<.>>--._>|--------|.>-^-.+++++++.<<<<!!!'
print ''.join((chr(93+len(x))if x else' ')for x in t.split('|'))
```

Uses a very simple trick - `|` characters were added to the BF program, and the distances between them encode the string printed in Python. The Python code is mostly ignored by BF.

Comment: Is it ok to print the '\0' at the beginning?

Comment: @V-X, Perhaps it isn't. The BF code is copied, and I noticed that `.join` added a `.`, but didn't see any harm (because `\0` is invisible). The `+` is and `.split` are OK - I removed the characters from the original.